# Save src data:image information as file

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

I am using classic asp and I have created a preview script in jQuery.

```
$('#file').change(function(){ 
    var oFReader = new FileReader(); 
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    oFReader.onLoad = function (oFREvent) {
       $('#preview').html('<img id="trial" src="' + oFReader.target.result + '">');
       };
});
```

This works add provides a preview of the image inside of the div called #preview.

What I now need to do is physically save the file into a directory on the website?

The resultant img tag has the following src value:

```
 src = 'data:image/PNG; base64,XXXXXXXXX'
```

Where XXXXXXXXX is a base 64 encode string and PNG is just the file type (can also be JPG, GIF, etc)

Comment: So what's the problem? Submit the form. Process it as any other file input.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way of doing this easily, so I created a .Net DLL to do that job for me.